# Powershell How to get if statement in a foreach loop to variable

Tags: powershell

How do you get an if statement output in a foreach loop to a variable?

Has 2 text files with pc names in

````
```
$Test1 = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt

$test2 = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test2.txt

foreach ($item1 in $Test1)
{

    foreach ($item2 in $test2)
    {
        if ( $item1 -eq $item2) 
        {
            Write-output $item1            
        }


    }

}

```
````

I can see all the pc names from Write-output  but  $item1 has only the last pc name

Comment: Shouldn't `$item1 -eq $test2` be `$item1 -eq $item2` (`$item2`, not `$test2`)?

Comment: Yeah, seems like you need to fix what @MathiasR.Jessen, pointed out. Regarding your question, are you wanting the output into a variable?

Comment: Sorry! And yes wanting the output into a variable

Comment: You can assign a variable to your `foreach` loop, or just to your output. `$NewVar = Foreach (…)`, or `$NewVar = $item1; $NewVar`, or your `if` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell allows you to capture the cumulative output from any flow control statement using a simple assignment (`=`):

```
$Test1 = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt
$test2 = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test2.txt

foreach ($item1 in $Test1)
{
    foreach ($item2 in $test2)
    {
        $outputFromIf = if ($item1 -eq $item2) 
        {
            Write-output $item1            
        }
    }
}
```

In your case - assuming you're expecting to find *multiple* matches - assigning the output from `if(){...}` will overwrite the value of `$outputFromIf` on every iteration, so you'll probably want to capture the output from the outer loop instead:

```
$outputFromLoop = foreach ($item1 in $Test1)
{
    foreach ($item2 in $test2)
    {
        if ($item1 -eq $item2) 
        {
            Write-output $item1            
        }
    }
}
```

Now `$outputFromLoop` will contain any output emitted from inside the outer `foreach($item1 in $Test1){ ... }` loop.

Comment: Just as an FYI... PowerShell offers a number of ways to do X or Y thingy. Here is another way you could have done this as a one-liner. `Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\TestFiles\Test2.txt' | ForEach-Object {($ResultData = Select-String -Path 'D:\Temp\TestFiles\Test1.txt' -Pattern $PSItem) -Replace '.*:'}`